# Executo a consulta PHP mas ela não exibe resultado da soma no MySQL

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldades de exibir a seguinte soma.

```
require_once("config_acesso.php");

$consultar = "SELECT SUM('valor') FROM vendascalc WHERE valor"; 
$resulta = mysqli_query($mysqli,$consultar);

echo "Total a pagar: " . $resulta;
```

Não obtenho nenhum resultado. Porém no phpMyAdmin o resultado flui tranquilo.

Comment: Não dá erro algum?

Comment: $consultar = "SELECT SUM('valor') FROM vendascalc WHERE valor"; ...valor o que?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro acerte a consulta, remova as aspas simples da coluna `valor`, defina um alias para o campo calculado dessa forma fica mais legível para recuperar os valores no php, caso não seja especificado nenhum apelido, o php assumirá que 'nome' é a expressão utilizada, no caso `sum(valor)` ou 0(zero) se utilizar `mysqli_fetch_array()`

```
$consultar = "SELECT SUM('valor') FROM vendascalc WHERE valor";
```

Mude para:

```
$consultar = "SELECT SUM(valor) as total FROM vendascalc WHERE valor";
```

Depois do `mysqli_query()` recupere o valor da consulta com `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` e faça uma laço para obter todas as linhas retornadas pela consulta.

```
$resulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consultar);

while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulta)){
   echo $item['total'] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: `WHERE valor` retorna as linhas onde `valor` não for `NULL`, `0` ou `''`; é válido e talvez seja a intenção.

Comment: @bfavaretto, hehe não conhecia essa sintaxe, parece ser melhor que usar `where valor is not null or valor <> ''` e afins vou alterar a resposta, \o valeu pela explicação.

Answer (score -1):

Sua query está errada, você precisa ter um valor depois de WHERE:

```
SELECT SUM('valor') FROM vendascalc WHERE valor = <algum numero>
```

Comment: Eventualmente, o guia [answer] pode alguma dica de por que alguém votou negativo.

Comment: Obrigado @perdeu, foi na mosca sua dica. Valeu.